# Akeneo 4: custom units of measure don't work

Tags: symfony4, akeneo

I'm trying to import my custom units of measure into Akeneo 4 that I had created in Akeneo 3.2, but, after cleaning the cache, the app does not work.

This is the tree of the bundle:
 [Bundle tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRAIb.png)

I activated the bundle in *conf/bundles.php:*

```
<?php

return [
    // Add your bundles here with the associated env.
    // Ex:
    // Acme\Bundle\AppBundle\AcmeAppBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Acme\Bundle\MyMeasureBundle\AcmeMyMeasureBundle::class => ['all' => true],
];
```

where is the error?

Comment: [Documentation](https://docs.akeneo.com/4.0/manipulate_pim_data/catalog_structure/how_to_add_a_custom_unit_of_measure.html#clear-the-cache-and-try-it-out) specify to delete all translation files inside of `/public/js/translation/`

Comment: Did you manage to make it work? I'm struggling with the same exact issue.

Comment: Self reply: to me it was something cache-related. I run Akeneo in docker, rebuilding the containers and triggering a cache + product index reset solved the issue.